# Laplacian Filter kernel size meaning

Tags: filters, frequency, opencv, kernel

I'm using laplacian filter in opencv.

I usually use laplacian filter with kernel size 3 which is default setting in opencv.

I'm just curious what happen(intuitively) when I choose bigger size kernel?

I think if I take small size such as 3x3, this gives me 3x3 matrix. So the result is "how much change in pixel intensity in 3x3 neighbors.

However if I take bigger size such as 7x7, this gives me 7x7 matrix. So the result is "how much change in pixel intensity in 7x7 neighbors.

So, intuitively I think small kernel size gives me small local change, on the other hand big kernel size gives me broader change.

Is is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, the *Laplacian()* operator applies a [Sobel filter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) and the *kernel_size* parameter specifies the dimensionality of that filter. Therefore, your intuition about applying the filter to a neighborhood proportional to the *kernel_size* is correct. Consider plotting the results of applying *Laplacian()* with various *kernel_size* values side by side if you want to solidify your intuition. I also recommend you look at *OpenCV*'s [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/db5/tutorial_laplace_operator.html) as it contains all the theory you need. I hope that helps!